# Hydrogen can be stored?

Tags: safety, hydrogen

Please tell about the hydrogen gas storage and the pressure created in tank. what is the calorific value of hydrogen gas when it is burnt?

Comment: I'll say wikipedia is pretty clear when it gets to explaining [Hydrogen storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_storage).

Answer (score 1):

> what is the calorific value of hydrogen gas when it is burnt?

286 kilojoules of energy is released per mole of hydrogen burned.

> Please tell about the hydrogen gas storage and the pressure created in tank.

In a tank at room temperature, hydrogen is a supercritical fluid, because the critical point is 33K.

In a tank, a long as the tank is strong enough, the pressure could be any value up to at least 10,000 psi, but at high enough pressure it would solidify.

For more information see [PROPERTIES OF HYDROGEN](http://www.bnl.gov/magnets/staff/gupta/cryogenic-data-handbook/Section3.pdf) (no paywall), especially page III-E for P-V-T information.